# Django Admin - Detect changes in inline fields

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am pretty new to python. I have Models named Project and ProjectTopic.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField()

class ProjectTopic(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

In the admin.py, I have added the ProjectTopic as an inline field. The admin can add as many topics that he likes.

Now the requirement is I need to send a notification if there is any change in the project that includes the ProjectTopic section. I have added

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if 'description' in form.changed_data:
        send_notification()

    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

But don't know how to track the changes in the inline ProjectTopic section.

Answer (score 9):

I have been looking into getting a proper solution to this as well. In case you are not strictly looking to access the changed inline fields from within the `Project` admin's `save_model()` method,  I can suggest three solutions. Even though it might not be the best solution, you can get your job done.

## Method 1

You can use the `save_related()` method as follows

```
def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):

    if form.changed_data:
        # Call function to notify change in Project fields
        send_project_notification()

    for form_set in formsets:
        if form_set.has_changed():
            # Call function to notify change in ProjectTopic fields
            send_project_topic_notification()

    super().save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
```

## Method 2

It would require you to use the [Field Tracker](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#field-tracker) using which you can track changes in model fields. Add the `project_topic_tracker` to your model and use a `post_save` signal to track the changes as follows.

**models.py**

```
class ProjectTopic(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    project_topic_tracker = FieldTracker()
```

**signals.py**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=ProjectTopic)
def notify_project_topic_change(sender, **kwargs):

    if 'instance' in kwargs:
        instance = kwargs['instance']

        if(
            hasattr(instance, 'project_topic_tracker') and 
            instance.project_topic_tracker.changed()
        ):
            changed_list = list(instance.project_topic_tracker.changed().keys())

            if changed_list:
                # Call your notification function
                send_project_topic_notification()
```

## Method 3

You can use a form `ProjectTopicForm` from whose `clean()` method you can access the changed data.

**forms.py**

```
class ProjectTopicForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ProjectTopic
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):

        if self.changed_data:
            send_project_topic_notification()
```

I have a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53932528/django-access-changed-inlineadmin-fields-within-parent-admins-save-model) for which I have been looking for work arounds