# Django - Access changed InlineAdmin fields within parent Admin's save_model()

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Apologize if this question has already been addressed before. Since I was not able to find a proper solution for this, had to ask.
I need to perform an action(an API call telling my clients to update models from their end) when there is a change in a model's Inline Admin fields from within the save_model() of the parent admin.

**models.py**

```
class Student(models.Model)
    name = CharField()
    age = DateField()

class Marks(models.Model)
    student = ForeignKey(Student)
    subject = CharField()
    marks = IntegerField()
```

**admin.py**

```
class MarksInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Marks
    form = MarksForm
    formset = MarksInlineFormSet

class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = StudentForm
    inlines = [MarksInline, ]
```

I am able to achieve this by checking the `form.changed_data` from within the `StudentAdmin` `save_model()` and for the `MarksInline` models `MarksInlineFormSet` `clean()` method. The issue is my action will be called separately from each of these methods resulting in two calls, even though all I need is a single call to update the `Student` and `Marks` model in the clients end.

My problem would be solved if the `save_model()` of `StudentAdmin` could return the fields that has been changed via `form.changed_data` in `MarksInline` as well.

Tried to use `post_save` signals as well by implementing [Field Tracker](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#field-tracker). But this too sent out separate `post_save` signal calls to the receiver function.

Does anyone know a work around using which I can figure out the changed fields of the InlineAdmin fields from within the parent Admins `save_model()` method.